# SEVERE: A child container failed during start

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Previously my tomcat server was working fine.

But suddenly getting following error.

Please help on this

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Project-1]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Project-1]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The
>   servlets named [Project-1] and
>   [com.example.project_1.Project_1UI$Servlet] are both mapped to the
>   url-pattern [/*] which is not permitted   at
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2466)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2148)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1293)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Nov 02, 2015 9:50:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on
>   classpath Nov 02, 2015 9:50:09 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Set web app root
>   system property: 'webapp.root' =
>   [C:\Users\syed\Documents.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\LorryHub]
>   Nov 02, 2015 9:50:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: Initializing log4j from
>   [C:\Users\syed\Documents.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\LorryHub\WEB-INF\log4j.lorryhub.properties]
>   log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\LorryHub\lorryhub.log (The
>   system cannot find the path specified)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)  at
>   org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Nov 02, 2015 9:50:10 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing
>   Spring FrameworkServlet 'MainWeb' Nov 02, 2015 9:50:18 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>     at
>
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Nov 02, 2015 9:50:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more

Thanks

Comment: Please give more details, like what you were trying to do, and what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the error log says it all. You have more than one servlet deployed on tomcat with the same URL pattern mapped in their web.xml [/*]
`The servlets named [Project-1] and [com.example.project_1.Project_1UI$Servlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/*] which is not permitted at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping`

This is confusing since the container will not know which servlet to invoke whenever you hit the URL `localhost:[yourPort]/[AppName-Maybe]/`. Try going through the web.xml and fixing this or you can post the same here and get additional help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as said, that both are mapped to the url-pattern which is not permitted, try to add two url-pattern in the mapping section. You can add same url-pattern if you want or can add two different url-patterns, I had the same problem... like below

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.example.project1.Project1Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Project1Servlet</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/Project1Servlet</url-pattern>
<!-- Adding two url-pattern helped me get through that problem. Try it, this might work for you, also I was using apache tomcat 9.0.55 version -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. I created new workspace and added server in it. It worked for me !!

Please change workspace and try adding server to fresh WS.